# Unexpected result. Expected to repeat path

Tags: neo4j

Example graph:

```
Matrix-->Neo
Matrix-->Morpheus
```

In neo4 version 1.* query returned both Neo and Morpheus

```
START n=node(0)
MATCH n<--matrix-->m
RETURN m
```

But in 2.* it return only Morpheus. Why ?

Real example:

```
Graph Setup:
create 
(_0:`Crew`  {`name`:"Neo"}),
(_1:`Crew`  {`name`:"Morpheus"}),
(_2:`World`  {`name`:"Matrix"}),
_2-[:LIVE]->_1,
_2-[:LIVE]->_0


Query:
START
   n=node(*)
MATCH
  n<--matrix-->Neo
WHERE
  n.name="Neo"
RETURN
  n,
  Neo
```

live test: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=vuo9ut

Actual result:

```
| n                      |  Neo                         |
| (0:Crew {name:"Neo"})  |  (1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})  |
```

Expected result:

```
| n                      |  Neo                         |
| (0:Crew {name:"Neo"})  |  (0:Crew {name:"Neo"})       |
| (0:Crew {name:"Neo"})  |  (1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the same query against different Cypher parser versions in the console you linked above. Just select "Options" in the upper right and choose "Cypher parser v1.9". Doing this for your example queries, I get the same result for both "Latest Cypher version" and "Cypher parser v1.9". If you are getting different results for the same query please submit an issue.

Note that the `START` clause is no longer necessary in Cypher, so (given your sample graph) your query could be rewritten like this:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)<-[:LIVE]-(w:World)-[:LIVE]->(neo:Crew)
WHERE n.name = "Neo"
RETURN neo, n

+------------------------------------------------+
| neo                      | n                   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"Morpheus"} | Node[0]{name:"Neo"} |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

This query is essentially asking "What other crew members live in the same world as Neo?". Looking at the data in your console and the query the results you report are what I would expect the query to return.

The reason you are not getting your expected results is that pattern does not exist in your graph. To get the results you are expecting you would have to modify the query to something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)<-[:LIVE]-(w:World)
WHERE n.name = "Neo"
MATCH (neo)<-[:LIVE]-(w)
RETURN neo, n

+------------------------------------------------+
| neo                      | n                   |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"Morpheus"} | Node[0]{name:"Neo"} |
| Node[0]{name:"Neo"}      | Node[0]{name:"Neo"} |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Which is essentially asking "What world does Neo live in? Who are all the crew members that live in this world, including Neo?"

Comment: It happens only on specific graph (witch I can't share :( ). Neo4j examples work as described from you. I will mark your answer as "Accepted".